# Transpose Dataset via R

Tags: r

My original Data set

```
Transaction   Item   Amount   
       1001    200       14
       1001    201       13
       1001    202       16
       1001    205       17
       1002    300       11
       1002    305       12
       1002    200       30
```

I am using this below code based on some expert advise.

```
by(dx,dx$Transaction,function(x)c(x$Item,sum(x$Amount),x$Amount))
```

My current output is ...

```
dx$Transaction: 1001
[1] 200 201 202 205  60  14  13  16  17
------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
dx$Transaction: 1002
[1] 300 305 200  53  11  12  30
```

But my desired out is

```
200 201 202 205  60  14  13  16  17
300 305 200  53  11  12  30
```

Is it possible to get rid of headings like... `dx$Transaction: 1001`? I have million rows to process via this function.

I am ok to use other function if necessary. Please help.

Comment: It's not clear what you want from your desired output. Do you want a single `data.frame`? Or a `list` with two components, where each of the two components is a vector, corresponding to the two lines of your desired output? Or something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the desired output is a 'matrix', we can use `stri_list2matrix` from `stringi`, which will pad `NAs` to the list elements with unequal lengths and convert the 'list' to 'matrix'.

```
#your code
l1 <- by(dx,dx$Transaction,function(x)c(x$Item,sum(x$Amount),x$Amount))
library(stringi)
m1 <-  stri_list2matrix(l1, byrow=TRUE)
matrix(as.numeric(m1), ncol=ncol(m1))
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9]
#[1,]  200  201  202  205   60   14   13   16   17
#[2,]  300  305  200   53   11   12   30   NA   NA
```

If you prefer to keep it in a list and just remove the attributes, one way is

```
lapply(seq_along(l1), function(i) l1[[i]])
#[[1]]
#[1] 200 201 202 205  60  14  13  16  17

#[[2]]
#[1] 300 305 200  53  11  12  30
```

Or assign the attributes to NULL

```
attr(l1, 'dimnames') <- NULL
attr(l1, 'class') <- NULL
attr(l1, 'call') <- NULL
l1
#[[1]]
#[1] 200 201 202 205  60  14  13  16  17

#[[2]]
#[1] 300 305 200  53  11  12  30
```

#### data

```
dx <- structure(list(Transaction = c(1001L, 1001L, 1001L, 1001L, 
1002L, 
1002L, 1002L), Item = c(200L, 201L, 202L, 205L, 300L, 305L, 200L
), Amount = c(14L, 13L, 16L, 17L, 11L, 12L, 30L)), 
.Names = c("Transaction", 
"Item", "Amount"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -7L))
```

Comment: @Murali No problem.  Glad to help you.  No idea who is downvoting.

Comment: @Akrun...I am not sure who down voted either. Either way your solution is great. I was able to save the matrix in csv and planning to process few million sales lines. My intention is run 'Mining high utility item set' on our transaction data (that process need specific data format).